# Convolution operator yields negative index of matrix

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

When I read about convolutional neural network from the internet, like this [one](http://jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/), mostly I found that discrete convolution operator is defined as follow:
$$C=I*F$$
$$C(x,y)={\sum_{a=0}^{k-1} }{\sum_{b=0}^{k-1}}I(x-a,y-b)F(a,b)$$

Where the size of $F$ is $k\times k$, Suppose that the size of F is $3\times 3$ and size of $I$ is $9\times 9$, then $C(1,1)=\dots +F(2,2)I(1-2,1-2)+\dots$ that is does not make sense when $I$ has negative index, how do I compute matrix $C$ ? does we change the way the matrix indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches that can be taken:

- Only use valid indices. Matrix C will then be smaller than matrix I, in your example it would be a 7x7 matrix (9 - 3 + 1 = 7). You may see this in neural network libraries as a convolution working with "valid" border.
- Use synthetic values, usually just 0, for out-of-bounds indices in matrix I in order to calculate C. This produces the same size output as input, so some neural network libraries note this with "same" border.

Your formula suggests "same" border is being used*, because it would be unusual to work with a matrix C starting from an offset corner. If you do use "same" borders, it is important to normalise your input image data pixels to mean 0, otherwise the synthetic border will appear as a strong edge to the kernels.

If you are developing your own CNN code, I would suggest using "valid" border mode, because it is simpler, and a more common approach. It will work just fine for image classification tasks.

---

* Actually I think the formula you have posted is over-simplified or even wrong. I would expect to see the term $I(x+a,y+b)$ so that the top left index of C stays as (1,1) for a "valid" border. For a "same" border, I would expect to see a centered kernel.

Comment: Thank you @Neil_Slater,..,btw what did you mean by centered kernel ?

Comment: @KikiRizkiArpiandi I mean index (0,0) is in the middle of the kernel, and it ranges from (-1,-1) to (1,1) for your 3x3 example. That would make your offset calculations work so that when C was same dimensions as I, then all edges were treated equally using the "same" border mode. Alternatively, you need a midpoint offset term in the equation (which is how you could the same effect practically in code)

Comment: I see, I think $C(x,y)=\sum_{a=0}^{k-1} \sum_{b=0}^{k-1} F(k-a,k-b)I(x+a,y+b)$

Comment: Will work for valid convolution

Comment: Yes, except you have mirrored the kernel (from how it is normally used)

Comment: So I have to mirror the kernel first, to make it work the way it is normally used

Comment: No, just use $F(a,b)$ like you do in the question. It is only the indexing into $I$ that needs fixing for "valid" border.

Comment: So $C(i,j)=\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} F(m+1,n+1) I(i+m,j+n) $ is convolution?

Comment: @KikiRizkiArpiandi: Yes it is, but not sure why you are adding the 1 offset to indexes in F, you seem happy with 0-index before? If your image and kernel start with co-ordinate (1,1) then your comment seems correct. There are lots of ways to notate it in maths, all roughly equivalent. When you convert to code, just be aware of the indexing scheme you want to use.

Comment: Thankyou now its clear, I am doing reserch in mathematical aspect of cnn, cnn is new things for me, when I read the paper or  books about ml or neural net, its seem that the notation is inconsistent,...since I decide to set the index of the image matrix and kernel to start with (1,1). Its feels comfortable to set the index for weight to start from (1,1)..

Comment: @KikiRizkiArpiandi: Yes it is a problem when reading articles on NNs that everyone uses slightly different notation and conventions.

Comment: Is there any book that about convolutional neural network with  detailed explanation? Do you have any suggestion, I am having hard time to figure out where the equation come from, many books and tutorial online just give the final result for doing backpropagation, and I guess because we have cool stuff like theano auto differentiation, its make people ignore how complicated the math behind it